# Linux from scratch moving from VirtualBox to USB drive

Tags: linux, virtualbox, laptop, lfs

I have successfully created Linux from Scratch based distribution in VirtualBox. I have dynamically allocated storage of max size 64 GB, with less than 7 GB space used in the .vdi file, and I want to install it to 16 GB USB drive and use it as a booting USB for my laptop.

**How can I achieve that?**

Edit: I have data in the ext4 partition in the virtual disk, and I need it to be bootable from UEFI, which is currently the biggest problem, I can't figure, how to do that for almost 5 days.

Edit 2: The virtual disk looks like this:[image]

Comment: Supposed your host runs linux, `qemu-img` might be the right tool. First, you will have to make sure that the partitions/file systems in your virtual image do not extend the size of the target (here: 16GB). Then you might use `qemu-img resize ... --shrink` (look at the man page! Only work on a copy of your .vdi file!!!). After that, if the virtual disk is still usable, you may convert it to raw format (`qemu-img convert .... -O raw ...`) and copy to your USB drive using `dd` command. READ THE MAN PAGES!

Comment: Is the image already UEFI bootable?  If not, then what are you using to boot with? grub or something different?

Comment: I have installed grub as the LFS book suggests it. I don't know, how to make it UEFI bootable. See the second edit.

Comment: Until your LFS system supports UEFI, there is no need to worry about the USB drive part. Start with this: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/lfs-uefi.txt Also, you will either be disabling secure boot, or you will be installing custom UEFI variables (which is a lot of trouble just to boot from a USB stick). Maybe you have a good reason... but I would consider just setting my UEFI to compatibility mode.

Comment: I can switch the UEFI to compatibility mode. Can you sum the lfs-uefi.txt as answer, so I can mark it as correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: With compatibility mode you don't need to worry about UEFI, so it's just a matter of installing grub on the USB drive, copying the file system to it, etc. ...and making sure your kernel has built-in support for your USB hardware. Search the web for "LFS on USB".

Comment: I can't find any working tutorial for this, can you send me some link?

Comment: Also, there is a problem, that my Dell laptop doesn't show disks in legacy mode and probably also messes with booting from USB.

Comment: Which Dell laptop do you have?

Comment: Dell G5 15(5587)

Comment: And in the bios, there is written, that the legacy is not intended for booting from hard drives.